# PHP timetable with timezone

Tags: php, time, timezone

I am trying to build a timetable that has timezones and so I know when i run $date by a var dump it will convert the time for me but when I try to echo it nothing happens I was wondering if there is a way to echo this change and where I add thing so the timetable works by weeks no dates as its reset at the end of each week, So I want to be able to input lets say monday 10am and have it changed per timezone.

```
$time = 23;
$date = new \DateTime("{$time}:00:00.000", new DateTimeZone('UTC') ); 
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne'); $date->setTimezone($timezone);
echo $date;
```

Comment: https://eval.in/629996 . now you can understand that since it's an object so you can't directly echo it. for further help https://eval.in/629997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `$date` is a `DateTime Object`, so you cannot directly `echo` it

check here:-

https://eval.in/629996

(if you check the printed output it clearly states `DateTime Object`)

BTW you can `echo` this object elements in below way:-

https://eval.in/629997

Comment: Very helpful thankyou! however is there anyway to return 09:00 and is there a way I can input a day i.e 1-7 for monday-sunday?

Comment: @DylanOakenfull  check the datatime manual for this, or ask a new question with input and expected output. You will definitely get answer. Thanks